# Share monitors and peripherals between Linux PC and 2020 Macbook Pro 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, kvm

I have a Linux PC tower, two monitors (one HDMI the other DisplayPort), and a keyboard/mouse.

I also have a 2020 Macbook Pro 13". I'd like to be able to use my two monitors + keyboard and mouse with my Macbook without having to unplug them from my Linux PC.

I'm aware I should get a docking station for the MacBook. However, I'm not sure how to share the monitors, keyboard, and mouse between the two computers.

Is there a simple KVM switch that will work?

Thanks.

Comment: KVM is the usual way to go but generally a KVM has *one* kind of display (HDMI **OR** DP **OR** DVI, etc.)  switcher so you'll likely have to figure that part out to go forward with this.

Comment: I think I can go with HDMI. One of my monitors has both outputs, while the other is just HDMI.

Do you have a recommendation for a KVM switch?

Comment: Sorry no. I have an old VGA/USB KVM and I only use the USB switching and just plug everything into my 2 monitors and switch on the monitor controls. Not as convenient but works and has the benefit of being really cheap, like me...

Comment: There  is  a software KVM called Barrier. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390988/119271) about  congenital multiple Macs to  a single monitor, keyboard, and mouse. It works on macOS, Windows, BSD, and Linux.